Passing a DataFrame to exec() in Python code
I am encountering an error when using exec() to execute a function that requires a DataFrame as input. Passing a dictionary containing all the required arguments, but getting the following error:
_exec_output = position_parity(**{'feature_importance':          Variable  Importance
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thank you!
The code used:
code = f"{func_name}(**{args})"
print(args)
exec(f"_exec_output = {code}", globals())


func_name and func_name are not defined.

@D.L func_name can be a name of any function that takes a DataFrame as input; in this case, it is 'pasition_parity' from the internal library
